# Specifying parameter values for use with ebextensions with ebcli

Tags: amazon-web-services, ebcli

In a config file in `.ebextensions` I can specify the following configuration for a parameter:

```
Parameters:
  Foo:
    NoEcho: false
    Type: String
    Description: The value I wish to set.
    ConstraintDescription: Some value
```

But... when I try and deploy this with `eb create` Amazon will fall over:

```
ERROR: "option_settings" in one of the configuration files failed validation. More details to follow.
ERROR: Missing value for required parameter: AWSESDomain
ERROR: Failed to launch environment.
```

From digging in the ebcli github and looking at the templates for simple Elastic Beanstalk deployments that it uses parameters of this sort for the RDS username and password when deploying with `eb create --database`, but I can't figure out how I might set these from a configuration file.

How can I set a parameter from a configuration file in `.ebextensions`?

Comment: Which parameter are you trying to set exactly? Is this your actual `.ebextensions` file?

Comment: I'm trying to define a custom parameter, and `.ebextensions` is a directory with lots of files?

Comment: Right, let me rephrase: it would be useful to see the actual file from `.ebextensions` where you are trying to create this custom parameter

Comment: I think it's a case where you are trying to set an option setting, but it can only be set along with another one. In this case, I think you'll have to set `AWSESDomain` along with whatever it is that you're already setting.